# Segmentation fault executing method

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator

The relevant (I think) lines of my coding are below.
What is meant is that there is a list of Clusters.
One of them, `base`, will absorb another one (the `aborbed`).
The `aborbed` cluster should be erased from the `list`.

First problem I encountered was that I needed to perform other operations in both `base` and `absorbed` clusters, after `while` cycle closes.
From my searches, I found the `= &(*li)` stuff.  What I understand is that I get a pointer to the address of the element `li` points to, although I cannot do  `absorbed = li`, because one is an iterator and the other a (simple?) ponter.  I'd appreciate some explanation on this.

Now, the bigger problem is that I get a sementation fault in the line `c->getPoints();` of the method `joinCluster()`
What am I doing wrong? What should I do an why?

I'm using g++ (GCC) 4.5.2 in Linux x86_64.

```
Cluster * base;
Cluster * absorbed;

list<Cluster>::iterator li = clusters.begin(); 
while ( li != clusters.end() ) {   
    if (li->getId() == p2) {
        absorbed = &(*li);
        li = clusters.erase(li);
    } else if (li->getId() == p1) { 
        base = &(*li);
    }
++li;
}

base->joinCluster(absorbed);


void Cluster::joinCluster(Cluster * c)
{
    set<unsigned int> pts = c->getPoints(); 
}

set<unsigned int> Cluster::getPoints()
{
return points;
}

class Cluster {
    private:
    std::set<unsigned int> points;
    public:
    std::set<unsigned int> getPoints();
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list<Cluster>::iterator li = clusters.begin(); 
while ( li != clusters.end() ) {   
    if (li->getId() == p2) {
        absorbed = &(*li);
        li = clusters.erase(li);
    } else if (li->getId() == p1) { 
        base = &(*li);
    }
++li;   // <----  Don't increment when you already deleted.
}
```

When you delete then last element in the list, `li` becomes `cluster.end()`. Then you increment it again and boom, you're out of bounds. `++li` should go in `else` block.

Note also, when you erase `li` from the container, `absorbed` holds an invalid adress.

Comment: You're right, I already corrected the `++li` part.  Regarding your second paragraph: when I erase an element from list, it's really erased from memory? or just removed from the list, but available "individually"?

Comment: @Luis Standard containers store elements by value. After you delete an element, it's gone, and all the iterators, pointers and references associated with it are invalidated. You'll have to do the "absorbsion" before you call `erase()` or make a copy of the element.