# Get iterator from pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator

Following question [Segmentation fault executing method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166462/segmentation-fault-executing-method) I stopped in another problem.

Given:

```
Cluster * base;
Cluster * absorbed;

list<Cluster>::iterator li = clusters.begin();

// li is then pointed to some element.

absorbed = &(*li);   // Get a pointer to the chosen element.

base->joinCluster(absorbed);   // Perform an action with absorbed.

// li contines the cycle and now point to clusters.end()

// Now, absorbed should be deleted from list. li doesn't point to absorbed anymore.
li = & (* absorbed);
clusters.erase(li);
```

Tried to do the reverse of above, but g++ returns an error: `error: no match for 'operator=' in 'li = absorbed'`
How can I do this?

I'm trying to avoid to cycle through all the elements in the list to find again the `absorbed` one.

**Edit:**

Sorry, but i understand I missed to say that after `absorbed = &(* li);` `li` continues to cycle until `clusters.end()`.
So, at the time the cycle ends, `li` doesn't point to `absorbed` anymore.
I think I have two option: Either I cycle again through all elements in `clusters` to find the `absorbed` element; Or I take advantage of the `absorbed` pointer to erase the element from `clusters`.  But, how can I achieve this second option?

Answer (score 4):

Just skip the `li = &(*absorbed)` line and it should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot get an `std::list<T>::iterator` from a `T*`. You'll have to use the original `li` to perform iterator operations.

Answer (score 3):

**Just erase it!**
No need for trying to put a value back in if you are going to delete it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
// Now, absorbed should be deleted from list
li = & (* absorbed);
clusters.erase(li);
```

use:

```
clusters.pop_front();
```

if you always process the first element.

There is no way to obtain an iterator from a value. Not the reason but the same value can be in multiple containers or more then once in one.